# Remove extra white space from between letters in R using gsub()

Tags: regex, r, gsub

There are a slew of answers out there on how to remove extra whitespace from between words, which is super simple. However, I'm finding that removing extra whitespace **within** words is much harder. As a reproducible example, let's say I have a vector of data that looks like this:

`x <- c("L L C", "P O BOX 123456", "NEW YORK")`

What I'd like to do is something like this:

`y <- gsub("(\\w)(\\s)(\\w)(\\s)", "\\1\\3", x)`

But that leaves me with this:

`[1] "LLC" "POBOX 123456" "NEW YORK"`

Almost perfect, but I'd really like to have that second value say "PO BOX 123456". Is there a better way to do this than what I'm doing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try this,

```
> x <- c("L L C", "P O BOX 123456", "NEW YORK")
> gsub("(?<=\\b\\w)\\s(?=\\w\\b)", "", x,perl=T)
[1] "LLC"           "PO BOX 123456" "NEW YORK"
```

It just removes the space which exists between two single word characters.

Comment: Simply amazing. Nice work, my friend! I'll accept in 8 minutes when I can.